# All nighter: steady sleep schedule or sleepping in

Tags: sleep

Staying up all night is harmful, but suppose you are in this situation what is the healthiest response. It is hard to find a scientific answer online on the healthiest response after staying awake all night. Most blog-answers suggest staying up all day and going to sleep at your normal sleeping time. But I am not sure if that is a good advice:

- Sleep deprivation is dangerous
- Both routes of (a)staying up all day and  (b)sleeping in, disrupt the sleep cycle for days, and I claim equally so.

I would appreciate references on any related studies on the healthy responses to staying awake all night.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You're going to need to clarify this question.

Comment: I updated the question, please be specific if there is something that confuses you so that I can help clarify.